# How to subplot + imagesc with a Position in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, matlab-figure, subplot

Situation: change Position of a single subplot with imagesc

```
%% Matlab recommends this structure if axes(); in loop
a1 = subplot(1,2,1); 
a2 = subplot(1,2,2); 
while 1    
    plot(a1, rand(3))    
    plot(a2, rand(3))    
    drawnow 
end

%% Test code
unitsPerInches=[0 0 15 15];
figure('Units', 'inches');
a1 = subplot(1,2,1); 
a2 = subplot(1,2,2); 
while 1    
    set(a1, 'Position', unitsPerInches); % TODO how to affect a1's Position here only? 
    imagesc(a1, rand(3))    
    imagesc(a2, rand(3))    
    drawnow 
end
```

Open

1. What is `imagesc` corresponding structure to `plot(a1,rand(3))`?
2. How to change `Position` of `figure` inside the loop?

### Forward in Q1 - almost done

```
%% Extension to imagesc
figure
a1=subplot(1,2,1);
a2=subplot(1,2,2);
for counter=1:2;
    imagesc(a1,rand(3))
    imagesc(a2,rand(3))
    drawnow    
end
```

Fig. 1 Output of Docs example, Fig. 2 Output of Imagesc, Fig. 3 about Q2 where Position affects both subplots

[image]
[image]
[image]

Q1 is almost done; I have just forgotten how to get corresponding plot in imagesc; x-values should be put there but pseudocode `imagesc(a1,XDATA,rand(3))` is unsuccessfuly.

### Backward in Q2

Code

```
%% Extension to imagesc
unitsPerInches=[0 0 15 15];
figure
a1=subplot(1,2,1);
a2=subplot(1,2,2);
for counter=1:2;
    set(a1, 'Position', unitsPerInches); % TODO how to affect a1's Position here only?
    imagesc(a1,rand(3))
    imagesc(a1,rand(3))
    drawnow    
end
```

Output: position affects both images in Fig. 3.

I think I have misunderstood the meaning of Position here because so strange output.

### Testing EBH's [proposal](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38883145/54964) for Q2

The implicit assignments cause problems when having two figures where subplots

```
unitsPerInches=[0 0 15 15];
aFig=figure();
a1=subplot(1,2,1);
a2=subplot(1,2,2);

bFig=figure();
b1=subplot(1,2,1);
b2=subplot(1,2,2);

for counter=1:2;
    if counter==1
        set(a1, 'Position', unitsPerInches); % affect only position of a1
    end
    subplot(1,2,counter);    
    imagesc(rand(3));
    drawnow    

    subplot(1,2,counter);    
    imagesc(rand(3));
    drawnow    
end
```

Output: second figure of subplots fails.

System: Linux Ubuntu 16.04 64 bit
Linux kernel 4.6
Matlab: 2016a
Related threads: [Matlab7 'bug' when using "subplot" + "imagesc"?](https://se.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/162195)

Comment: Here a good answer to update from Matlab 2014 syntax to Matlab 2016 http://stackoverflow.com/a/39877470/54964 for subplots and having them in arrays.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure what you're asking, but I think it's about combining multiple `imagesc` statements while in a loop. I'd do something more direct -- use `gca` and put the subplot inside the loop. Quite often, if you want to programmatically address multiple images, it makes sense to put them in some sort of structure other than creating lots of differently named variables. Note also that `while 1` is probably not really what you want -- it will hammer your graphics device drivers -- and that `pause` can take an argument to act as a wait function, for some fraction of a second if required.

```
testImages{1}=double(imread('coins.png')); 
testImages{2}=double(imread('cameraman.tif')); 

h=figure; 
set(h,'color','w'); %This handle refers to the background window 


for ix=1:2 
     subplot(1,2,ix); 
     imagesc(testImages{ix}); 
     axis equal;
     colormap gray; 

     %Change, for example, axis position
     curPoss=get(gca,'Position'); %gca stands for 'get current axis'
     set(gca,'Position',curPoss+1e-2*ix^2); %Move one image up a bit
end
```

Does that help?

[image]

Comment: I am not completely sure about putting the subplot inside the loop because Matlab's documentation says that you should not do it; etc if you are using `axes()` function. To have `subplot` inside the loop is taking significant resources. - - Also, you have only one figure object. It can be correct, not sure. Assume that you want to have different `unitsPerInches` in two plots in the subplot. How to deal with it?

Comment: I use a similar method in a simulation displaying 2 `imagesc` that are constantly refreshed in different subplots, and hence I have to "move" between them all the time within the loop, and it works just fine.

Comment: Please, see the body. Preallocation works well with `imagesc` too. Now, only Q2 is the problem with the Position. I think I have misunderstood its meaning.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to jump between figures, make an array of them, and use it within a loop:

```
unitsPerInches = [0.1 0.1 0.15 0.15];
figs = [figure(1) figure(2)];

for f = 1:numel(figs)
    figure(figs(f));
    for counter = 1:2;
        subplot(1,2,counter);
        imagesc(rand(3));
        drawnow
    end
    figs(f).Children(1).Position = unitsPerInches;
    figs(f).Children(2).Position = unitsPerInches+0.3;
end
```

Your original values for `unitsPerInches` was wrong, since the [`'Position'`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/axes-properties.html#property_Position) property of an `axes` takes values between 0 to 1 by default. You can change this using the [`'Units'`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/axes-properties.html#property_Units) property, like:

```
figs(f).Children(1).Units = 'inches';
```

The output from this example is two figures that looks like this:

[image: fig_1]

Where there is a small axes on the down-left and a big one on the top-right.

So, back to your original questions:

> 1. What is `imagesc` corresponding structure to `plot(a1,rand(3))`?

Instead of passing the axes to `imagesc`, set the focus on the relevant figure, and subplot with:

```
figure(h)
subplot(x,y,c)
imagesc(data)
```

where `h` is a handle to the relevant figure, `c` is the place of the subplot within `h` where you want to plot the image (a number between 1 to `x*y`), and after these two line you call `imagesc`.

> 2. How to change `'Position'` of figure inside the loop?

In this question it is not clear if you want to change the 'Position' of the [*figure*](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/figure-properties.html#property_Position) or the [*axes*](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/axes-properties.html#property_Position), they have different units and meaning, but both are accessible in the same way:

```
h.Position = [left bottom width height]; % for the position of the figure
h.Children(c).Position = [left bottom width height]; % for the position of the axes
```

where `h` is as before, but `c` may be numbered differently, so `subplot(x,y,c)` may not refer to the same axes as `h.Children(c)`. However, you can always use `gca` to get the current axes handle:

```
ax = gca;
ax.Position = [left bottom width height];
```

Hope it's all clear now, and if there are further questions, let me know ;)

Comment: @Masi take a look at my edit to the answer. Let me know if anything is left open ;)

Comment: Assume each figure has different number of subplots. Can you loop the subplots of each figure like you do for `figs`?

Comment: (1) the syntax in `figure('Units', 'inches', 'Position', unitsPerInches);` is right, though I don't know what you try to draw, so I can't tell if this is the way to do so. (2) You can loop on the subplots, but the way to implement this is dependent on how your loop looks like. For instance, you can set the counter to iterate on different number of subplots (if you don't know how many there are maybe you can use `numel(hFig.Children)` to get their number), and some other methods are available, but the most elegant and quick way depends on your need.

Comment: @Masi, if nothing is left open, can you mark this question as "answered"?

Comment: I do it as soon as possible. I want to test it thoroughly in my system. I have the following condition at the moment in my system which is preventing my proceeding https://github.com/altmany/export_fig/issues/171 The function `export_fig` is giving unstably `I` after the changes, and I do not understand why so.

Comment: Well, I don't use `export_fig`, so I have nothing to say about this, but take your time, and come back here I there's anything new.