# How to rewrite this Matlab 2014 code with axis-subplots to 2016?

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, subplot

Code which I wrote for Matlab 2014 but which I want to rewrite it to Matlab 2016 such that it becomes more compact, since it is extranous now

```
hFig3=figure('Units', 'inches');
hax3_b1=axes('Parent', hFig3);
hax3_b2=axes('Parent', hFig3);
hax3_b3=axes('Parent', hFig3);
hax3_b4=axes('Parent', hFig3);

b1=subplot(2,2,1, hax3_b1); 
b2=subplot(2,2,2, hax3_b2); 
b3=subplot(2,2,3, hax3_b3); 
b4=subplot(2,2,4, hax3_b4);

% Example of common expression
set([b1 b2], 'Units', 'inches'); % http://stackoverflow.com/a/39817473/54964

u=0:0.1:1; y=sin(u); C = [0 2 4 6; 8 10 12 14; 16 18 20 22];
imagesc(b1, u, y, C); 
hold on; 
plot(b2, u'); 
histogram(b3, u');
histogram(b4, u);
hold off; 
drawnow;
```

Output is ok

[image]

OS: Debian 8.5 64 bit
MATLAB: 2014 but want to convert to 2016

Comment: If you really have to save some characters: I don't think lines 2-5 are necessary, and the same goes for the 4th arguments in `subplot`.

Comment: You are doing something wrong if they are necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply write:

```
figure('Units','inches');
b1 = subplot(2,2,1); 
b2 = subplot(2,2,2); 
b3 = subplot(2,2,3); 
b4 = subplot(2,2,4);
```

or preferably, if you want to have an array of the axes:

```
figure('Units','inches');
b(1) = subplot(2,2,1);
b(2) = subplot(2,2,2);
b(3) = subplot(2,2,3);
b(4) = subplot(2,2,4);
```

or use a simple `for` loop:

```
figure('Units','inches');
b(1:4) = axes;
for k = 1:numel(b)
    b(k) = subplot(2,2,k);
end
```

In any option you choose there is no need for all the `axes` commands.

Here is all your 'demo' code:

```
b(1:4) = axes;
for k = 1:numel(b)
    b(k) = subplot(2,2,k);
end
set(b(1:2), 'Units', 'inches');
u=0:0.1:1; y=sin(u); C = [0 2 4 6; 8 10 12 14; 16 18 20 22];
imagesc(b(1), u, y, C); 
plot(b(2), u'); 
histogram(b(3), u');
histogram(b(4), u);
```

There might be no real need also in the `figure` command, it depends on what do with it.

Comment: @Masi, I prefer to use matrices (i.e. `b(1)`)  where I can and not cell arrays, because they are more fast and convenient. I don't know if there is a standard, but from what I see around, it's better to use a robust type of variable then a fluid one like cells, if possible. Also, `arrayfun` is neither faster nor simpler the a small `for` loop, and the latter one is much more flexible, so I tend to prefer those.

Comment: @Masi, you don't initialize an `axes` matrix with `zeros`... have a look on my edit for more details and corrections (i.e. no need in `hold` and `drawnow`).

Comment: @Masi If you want to name the figure then use the `figure` command. Nothing is wrong with it, it's just that in most  cases it's not really needed because `axes` always creates a figure to 'live' in.

Comment: @Masi the default units of the `position` property are [normalized](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/axes-properties.html#property_Units) (i.e. from 0 to 1 as a fraction of the figure size). Once you set the `Units` to `inches` you lose the scalability of the axes, because MATLAB keeps the `position` as an _absolute_ value in inches.

Answer (score 2):

If you're just looking for shorter you can eliminate most of the stuff at the beginning.  You don't need the `figure` but I keep it as a matter of habit.

```
fh = figure;
x = 1:4;
b = arrayfun(@(y) subplot(2,2,y), x, 'UniformOutput',0);
b{1}.Units = 'inches';
b{2}.Units = 'inches';
u=0:0.1:1; y=sin(u); C = [0 2 4 6; 8 10 12 14; 16 18 20 22];
imagesc(b{1}, u, y, C); 
plot(b{2}, u'); 
histogram(b{3}, u');
histogram(b{4}, u);
```

Comment: @Masi the elements in `b` are `axes` objects.

Comment: @Masi no, the output of `subplot` is an axes object.  The `arrayfun` just collects the objects into a cell array.  The old graphics system was built around figure handles.  The new system uses objects.  It was changed in 2014b I believe.

Comment: Why would you not use `figure`? What does naming a figure have to do with axes?

Comment: @Masi you are getting way beyond what you asked.  But the `axes` object contains a link to its parent.  `movegui(fh, 'north')` works just fine.  Also `b{1}.Parent == fh` results in true.

Comment: @Masi, the questions are fine, you are just getting deeper into the graphics system.  I said that because if you want to continue to explore the those details perhaps another question so that people can better find the answers as well.

Comment: @Masi, what do you mean "a figure for all subplots"  Subplots are part of other figures.  Do you want to convert a `subplot` into a regular `plot`?

Comment: @Masi do you *ever* read the documentation? The documentation for [`subplot` explicitly states](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/subplot.html#namevaluepairarguments): "You can set any axes properties for a subplot" and links directly to the [Axes properties documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/axes-properties.html), where you'll see a [`'Parent'`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/axes-properties.html#property_Parent) property.